# command: ls /etc | sort | grep d* is yielding no results but ls /etc | sort | grep p* lists entire directory

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, quoting

I am playing around with piping and grep tonight.  I know that grep uses regex and that * means 0 or more occurrences of the preceding character.  So the way I understand it is that if I do the following command, the entire directory should be listed... but nothing is listed.  All that happens is the command line resets:

```
[root@LinuxAcademy etc]# ls /etc | sort | grep d*
[root@LinuxAcademy etc]#
```

However, if I do the command again and replace d with p, the entire directory is listed just as I would expect:

```
[root@LinuxAcademy ~]# ls /etc | sort | grep p*
ConsoleKit
DIR_COLORS
DIR_COLORS.256color
DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor
NetworkManager
X11
...........<<rest of listing not pasted in>>
```

Even though no error was given when i used the grep d*, I redirected stderr to a file just to check and nothing was printed.

I then thought that grep may be interpreting the 'd' in 'grep d*' to be an option or command... but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on and why when i use the command with

```
grep d*
```

nothing is listed?

Answer (score 10):

A regular expression is not a glob.

I am guessing that you want files that start with "d".  In that case, you need:

```
ls /etc | sort | grep '^d'
```

#### What went wrong

How the following statement behaves depends on the files in the current directory:

```
ls /etc | sort | grep p*
```

Since it is unquoted, the shell will try to expand the glob `p*`, replacing it with whatever file names *from the current directory* match.

If no file names match, then a literal `p*` is passed to `grep`.  Since `grep` expects regular expressions, it interprets `p*` to mean zero or more occurrences of the letter `p`.  Since everything either has a `p` or doesn't, *that matches everything*.

#### Why would `grep d*` list nothing?

That likely means that there was a file name starting with `d` in the current directory.  Just to be specific, let's say that file's name was `dichotomy`.  The shell expands `d*` to `dichotomy` and passes that as the argument to `grep`.  Thus, the effective command is:

```
grep dichotomy
```

That is likely why there were no results when you ran `grep d*`.

#### What happens if multiple files match the `d*` glob?

Consider the command:

```
grep d*
```

If their are multiple files matching that glob, say `dmesg` `daemon.log` and `dpkg.log`.  The shell would expand `d*` to the list of those files in alphabetical order (which depends on your locale).  This may result in:

```
grep daemon.log dmesg dpkg.log
```

This command searches for the presence of the string `daemon.log` in the files `dmesg` and `dpkg.log`.  If that string does not occur in those files, no output results.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.  I do really appreciate the explanation of processing order.

What you said happens with p* is exactly what I expected.  I also expect it when I use d*.... but nothing happens and that's the trivia here that I have.  

I am not trying with any specific purpose but to produce unexpected results and better understand the processing... which you did help me do so thank you.

So why doesn't grep d* list entire directory just like grep p*.   That's what I don't get.

Comment: Oddly, the user's current directory is called `etc` in the first command, presumably `/etc`, so at least the directory whose name the glob was expanded into should have been matched. @BradHarris try this: After typing the command, press `Tab` - bash will try to autocomplete the `d*` glob. This will let you see what `d*` actually expands into before grep gets a hold of it.

Comment: Oh man I didn't put 2 & 2 together when the processing path/order was explained when using p*.  Thank you for the understanding.  It's this understanding that I want to be sure I really get.  I see it now.

Comment: So I tested out the theory when grep d* is used.  example: dmesg, daemon.log, and dpkg.log are the only files/dirs in the current directory that start with d.  I copied those to the /etc directory.  when I pass grep dmesg the result is dmesg.  when i pass grep d*, therefore, it should at least print out a filename that starts with d because the shell would expand the d* to a name that is in both the current direction (and so was expanded to that name) but also in the directory being listed (/etc) and so grep would find it and return that.  but nothing is returned still :(

Comment: Ok, got it.  Here's what's happening, when I was using d* it was trying to expand to a filename but there were multiple possible expansions and that would have been the failure I think.  I tried a couple tests and when I use the * and the possible expansion is more than one, this behavior happens.

Comment: @BradHarris Yes, you got it.  To explain in more words, I just added a section to the answer on the issue of multiple matches.