# Understanding the 'grep' command, shows different results than expected

Tags: command-line, grep, ls, tcsh

I'm new to Unix and trying to show all the files (without directories) in my directory, so I use the command `ls -p | grep -v /`.

It shows me a list that looks something like this:

```
Process1
Process2 
Process3
   ︙
```

But when I use the command `ls -p | grep -v / | grep P*`, it shows only some of the processes. Why don't all of the processes show?

**EDIT**

I realized that I used capital P instead of lower case p. This is a mistake.

Comment: Process? You mean "files"?

Comment: Do you have several files named `Process...`?

Comment: It's not really "Process", it's some other names but all start in the same letter and only some show when I use `ls -p | grep -v / | grep P*`

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using tcsh.

Comment: In some 30 years of UNIX, this is the first time I saw somebody actually use `ls -p`.  Congratulations, there must be a prize waiting for you somewhere. :)

Comment: See [List only regular files (but not directories) in current directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116524) for instance. Using `ls -p` for the purpose of filtering (in or out) directories is not uncommon (even though it's flawed in that it doesn't handle filenames with newline characters).

Comment: I actually learned to use `ls -p` from the link above, but i'll still have my prize please.

Comment: (1) Please don’t use `Process1`, `Process2`, `Process3`, etc., as example ***file*** names.  This is almost as confusing as using `Directory1`, `Directory2`, and `Directory3` as example file names and `File1`, `File2`, and `File3` as example directory names.  More to the point, don’t say that `ls` lists processes; that’s wrong.  (2) Please don’t edit your question to say “I made a mistake.”  Edit it ***to fix the mistake.***  Add a comment if people have clearly been investing a lot of effort into the wrong version of the question, but don’t clutter up the question itself with change markings.

Comment: Also, see [command `ls /etc | grep d*` is yielding no results but `ls /etc | grep p*` lists entire directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149340/23408).

Answer (score 3):

The **`"P*"`** would be matching something (or **not**) from your shell before grep sees the parameter.  If you quote it, you'll get better results, but bear in mind that grep matches regular expressions rather than globs.

So just a "P" would work.  Because it is a regular expression, you do not need the asterisk `*` to allow the characters following **`"P"`** to be matched (grep ignores those by default):

```
ls -p | grep -v / | grep "P"
```

or

```
ls -p | grep -v / | grep '^P'
```

Following up on the altered question, to ignore case, use the `-i` option of grep, e.g.,

```
ls -p | grep -v / | grep -i '^P'
```

Further reading:

- [grep - search a file for a pattern](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

  > **`-i`**
  >   Perform pattern matching in searches without regard to case; see XBD [Regular Expression General Requirements](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_02).
- [ls - list directory contents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html)

  > **`-p`**
  >   Write a  ( **`'/'`** ) after each filename if that file is a directory.

Comment: But i'm only looking for files that start with p, so using `grep p` will return more results than needed

Comment: Your question was unclear, but I addressed that in the last line of this answer.  By the way, your comment uses **p** rather than **P**.  If you want to ignore *case*, you should have made that part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

In your second command, you `grep P*`.  This will prompt the shell to do filename globbing on `P*`, i.e. it will expand `P*` to all files starting with the letter `P`.

Use `set -x` in your shell to see what gets executed (turn tracing off with `set +x`). *I actually have tracing turned on by default in my own interactive shell sessions just to see what I'm doing*.

Just double-quoting `P*` won't solve this as the *regular expression* `P*` also matches filenames such as `APPLE` and `file.PP`, and actually `hello_world.c` and all other filenames as well as `P*` also matches filenames with *no* `P`s in them.

Generally, [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) though, so the following would be a better way of getting a list of files (not directories) starting with the letter `P`:

```
$ find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "P*"
```

This will find all regular files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`) with names starting with `P` (`-name "P*"`). The `-maxdepth 1` option restricts `find` to only this directory. It would otherwise recurse down into subdirectories as well.

To do with `find` what you're doing with `grep -v /`, i.e. *removing* the directories from the list rather than *selecting* the regular files:

```
$ find . ! -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "P*"
```

This will also find non-regular files, such as sockets etc. In some shells it's necessary to escape or quote the `!`, i.e. saying

```
$ find . "!" -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "P*"
```

or

```
$ find . \! -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "P*"
```

Note that the quoting of `P*` is important so that your shell doesn't expand it.

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain what this command with these parameters do?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas
I changed `-type f` to `!type d` and it says `type: Event not found`

Comment: @PanthersFan92 `! -type d`